# Loosing __type__ under load?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Neo4j 1.9.2, SDN 2.3.0.M1, SpringFramework 3.2.3.RELEASE.

I have a stress test running against my application which consists of two microservices using async processing to exchange messages. The source service is Neo4J.

The general flow 
store~>message->process~>message~>retrieve

During store, I persist startnode, endnode and a property based relationship within a single transaction. All good. Message handoffs are async.

I'm testing the above flow with ~1000 requests fired off in a non-threaded JUnit test.

During the retrieve step maybe once or twice and sometime never, I get the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: '__type__' property not found for RelationshipImpl #3027 of type 9 between Node[1009] and Node[1516].
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.newPropertyNotFoundException(Primitive.java:193)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.getProperty(Primitive.java:188)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipImpl.getProperty(RelationshipImpl.java:29)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipProxy.getProperty(RelationshipProxy.java:114)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:107)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.readAliasFrom(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:36)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.readAliasFrom(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:26)
at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:101)
at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.getDefaultedTypeToBeUsed(DefaultTypeMapper.java:164)
at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:141)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:76)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:192)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.findOne(Neo4jTemplate.java:155)
at com.auditbucket.engine.repo.neo4j.dao.AuditDaoNeo.getChange(AuditDaoNeo.java:239)
at com.auditbucket.engine.service.AuditService.handleSearchResult(AuditService.java:411)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Am pretty sure it's something to do with the SDN/Neo4J libs. There is no way the relationship does not exist as it's created and the Id is sent over the message Q. Hard to see how the transaction is not committed. Code block included for completeness anyways

```
    ....
    AuditChange change = auditDAO.save(fUser, input, txRef);
    AuditLog log = auditDAO.addLog(header, change, fortressWhen);
    input.setStatus(AuditLogInputBean.LogStatus.OK);

    if (searchActive) {
        // Used to reconcile that the change was actually indexed
        sd.setLogId(log.getId());
        searchGateway.makeChangeSearchable(sd);
    }
    return input;
```

Comment: Do you use Neo4j embedded or server?

Comment: Appols! Must have edited that vital little fact out - embedded.

Comment: Would you be able to extract that into a standalone project with that junit-test? Would love to be able to track it down and fix. If so send an email to michael at neo4j dot org

Comment: This looks to be a race condition. From the Log, the Spring container acknowledges the transaction is committed in the Main thread. The last thing the Transactional method does is hand off to an Async task. The Async thread then attempts to read the relationship some time later and the exception is thrown. Asking the Async method to Thread.sleep(50) the problem goes away but this is a nasty hack. Likewise, I could put a facade in front of my Service to call the Async method independently after we're SURE the transaction has committed but this too is a hack.